# Change the color of an SVG image imported via the SVG Image's href attribute in React

Tags: reactjs, image, svg, puppeteer

I have an image tag that is used to import an SVG image (this is dynamically fetch from a selection of possible SVG that the customer can choose and the color of the image is mandatory to be black-filled for all paths of the selected SVG).

```html
<svg>
  <!-- some more SVG elements -->
  <image href={selectedSvgImagePath} />
  <!-- some more SVG elements -->
</svg>
```

In React, this works well and is perfectly rendered. Meaning the selected SVG image is displayed and rendererd correctly.

I then use Puppeteer to render the page in PDF and have a need to change the color for this particular `selectedSvgImagePath` tag. I tried to add a `fill="blue"` tag to the `<image>` tag like so.

```html
<image fill="blue" href={selectedSvgImagePath} />
```

But it didn't change the color of the imported SVG image. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: have a blue version of the image and change the reference to that image.

Comment: I'll edit my answer but unfortunately, I have only control over the image format, not the color one (they are all mandatory black-filled paths).